# Meteor element in array of a array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Basically wanted to push data within array of array i.e publicHolidays is outer array and holidayList is inner array. This is mongodb schema looking right now.

```
"publicHolidays" : [
        {
                "location" :"pune"
                "year" : 2016
                "holidayList"[
                        {
                               "holidayDate" :"2016-11-09",
                                "holidayName":"Diwali"

                        }
                ]
        }
]

I am expecting below schema,wanted to push data in holidayList.

"publicHolidays" : [
        {
                "location" :"pune"
                "year" : 2016
                "holidayList"[
                        {
                               "holidayDate" :"2016-11-09",
                                "holidayName":"Diwali"

                        }
                        {
                               "holidayDate" :"2016-1-09",
                                "holidayName":"padwa"

                        }
                        {
                               "holidayDate" :"2016-12-10",
                                "holidayName":"holi"

                        }
                ]
        }
]
```

Comment: Where is your code..?

Comment: Where are you expecting this? At the DB or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issue:

```
    //Add Holidays in Exist Location
    'companySettings.updatePublicHolidays'(formValues){
    CompanySettings.update(
        { 
          '_id': formValues.UniqueID,
          'publicHolidays' : {$elemMatch : {'location': formValues.holidaysLocation,'year': formValues.holidayYear} }
        },  
        {
            $push : {'publicHolidays.$.holidayList': 
                        {
                            'holidayDate' : formValues.leaveDate , 
                            'holidayName' : formValues.holidayName
                        }
                    }
        }
    );

},
```